# Where is the object in the sentence?

Tags: objects, imperative-sentences, subject-vs-object-pronouns

In the example of

> John baked Mary a cake for her birthday.

and

> John cried a river of tears over Mary.

Which is the object in the sentences? Are both the object 'Mary'? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Mary might be the object of John's affection and the cause of his tears, but **Mary** is not the grammatical direct object of the verb **baked**, rather **a cake** is; and **a river of tears** is the direct object of **cried**.

In the cake example, **Mary** occupies the indirect object position.

In the tears example, **Mary** is the object of the preposition **over**.